# How to post particular format to get json data in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, swift

How to post this type of format

```
 {
"Authentication": {
  "Username": "testUser@123",
  "Password": "testPassword@123"
},
"FileID": "2",
"RequestType": 5
}
```

I know how to post this type of format to json in objective-c, here is my code

```
   NSURL *url=[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://adservicedev.azurewebsites.net/order/json/process"];
dict = @{@"Authentication":@{@"Username":@"testUser@123",@"Password":@"testPassword@123"},@"RequestType":[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]};
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:dict])
{
    __jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil];
    __jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:__jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Error %@", __jsonString);
}
// Be sure to properly escape your url string.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: __jsonData];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[__jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&theResponse error:&errorReturned];
```

but am new to swift language,how to write the same in swift.Please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please let me know if any one knows?

Comment: No one knows answer for my question? Please need help

Answer (score -1):

Well that's the way you need to implement.

> **Swift code**

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/php/index.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
let postString = "" // if you want to pass some string to the url you can also do it here i.e type=user now on php side you can get the value by using $_GET['type'] or $_REQUEST['type']
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
 {
        data, response, error in

 if error != nil
 {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
  }
 var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

 var FileID : NSString = jsonResult["FileID"]! as NSString
 var RequestType : NSString = jsonResult["RequestType"]! as NSString
 let Auth : AnyObject = jsonResult["Authentication"]!
 var Username : NSString = Auth["Username"]! as NSString
 var Password : NSString = Auth["Password"]! as NSString
        println("Username : \(Username)")
        println("Password : \(Password)")
        println("RequestType : \(RequestType)")
        println("FileID : \(FileID)")
        println("Auth : \(Auth)")
 }
 task.resume()
```

> **PHP code (index.php)**

```
<?php

$v = '{"Authentication": {"Username": "testUser@123","Password": "testPassword@123" },"FileID": "2","RequestType": 5}';
echo $v;

?>
```

> **Final Output**

[image: Final output]

Comment: I need to post the above format and getting another json data.

Comment: Please anyone help? am very new to swift

Comment: am getting fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: this means you are getting a nil in any of the values.Try to debug the code  or remove the ! in jsonresult["all of them"]

Comment: Can you see my updated question and try to help me??